# BIND9 how to have 2 reverse resolutions for 2 different domains

Tags: bind, reverse-dns

I have one server Bind9 and 2 different domains.

I'ld like to have reverse resolution for each domain.

I've tried this configuration below but I get the error in `named-checkconf` :
`/etc/bind/named.conf:30: zone '10.0.10.in-addr.arpa': already exists previous definition:/etc/bind/named.conf:19`

My configuration :

```
zone "ngux.org" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/db.ngux.org";
    allow-transfer { 10.0.10.99; };
};
zone "10.0.10.in-addr.arpa" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/db.ngux.org.rev";
    allow-transfer { 10.0.10.99; };
};
zone "ldap.ngux.lan" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/db.ldap.ngux.lan";
    allow-transfer { 10.0.10.99; };
};
zone "10.0.10.in-addr.arpa" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/db.ldap.ngux.lan.rev";
    allow-transfer { 10.0.10.99; };
};
```

What should I do ? Have only one file for the 2 reverses addrreses ?
Thanx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reverse resolution is not bound to the forward DNS entry.

You need a zone for the subnet. `ngux.org` and `ngux.lan` can both be written to the same reverse zone. Simply deleting the second reverse zone will achieve what you want.